# "print" after "msvcrt.getch" doesn't work

Tags: python, passwords, msvcrt, getch

So, I am using python and I wrote a code to scan a password. So, as password should not be displayed openly, I scan one character using `msvcrt.getch()` and then do `print('*', end='')`.

Here's the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = ''
    ch = msvcrt.getch()
    while ch != b'\r':
        print('*', end='')
        string += ch.decode('utf-8')
        ch = msvcrt.getch()
    print('\nEntered string is: ', string)
```

The problem here is, the ***'s** are getting printed after I type the whole "password". But, what I was expecting is a ***** getting printed every time I enter a character. **I am running the code in terminal**.


I think I structured the code properly so why doesn't it work?

(Also, if there are any others ways of scanning passwords, please do mention them)

Answer (score 0):

However I'm not familiar with msvcrt if printing '*'s is not that important, you can use the [getpass](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html) standard library.

Comment: As a part of User Experience, I think it would be nice to have a '*' being printed for every character.